# Generic Grouping Using Linq

Tags: linq, grouping, pivot-table

```
EmployeeName    EmployeeNumber AllowanceName    Amount

ABDEL           002285          Housing         100.00
ABDEL           002285          Tickets         12.083
ABDEL           002285          Transportation  100.00
MOHAMED         001546          Tickets         150.00
MOHAMED         001546          Transportation  0.935
```

I need to convert this flat table to crosstabulation table to be like this

```
EmployeeName    EmployeeNumber      Housing  Tickets  Transportation  

ABDEL           002285              100.00   12.083   100.00  
MOHAMED         001546              0.000    150.00   0.935
```

Comment: How are you eventually displaying this?  There are UI and reporting controls that handle pivot tables dynamically better than Linq can.

Comment: You should normalize this table. `AllowanceName` should instead be a foreign-key to another table.

Answer (score 0):

Not really generic but maybe sufficient:

```
var query = empmloyee
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.EmployeeName, x.EmployeeNumber })
    .Select(gx => new { 
        EmployeeName   = gx.Key.EmployeeName,
        EmployeeNumber = gx.Key.EmployeeNumber,
        Housing        = gx.Where(x => x.AllowanceName == "Housing")
                           .Sum(x => x.Amount),
        Tickets        = gx.Where(x => x.AllowanceName == "Tickets")
                           .Sum(x => x.Amount),
        Transportation = gx.Where(x => x.AllowanceName == "Transportation")
                           .Sum(x => x.Amount),
    });
```